# Volume control problem

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control, amixer

When you change the sound through the system mixer, the speaker value changes, but the headphone value remains the same, because of this the sound is distorted, but if you change both of these values at the same time, then everything is fine and the sound changes smoothly. Is it possible to do something so that when changing the value of the system mixer, both of these values changed?